# mysql_query is not wanting to work in side php

Tags: php, mysql

OK so iam having a issue getting mysql_query to connect into the data base inside php. 
i did a quick test to see if it would connect and this is what i did. to for warn you iam new to php so if there is mistakes please let me know.

```
<?php    
require 'conect.php';
$query = "SELECT 'food', 'calories' FROM 'food' ORDER BY 'id'";
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'true';
}else{
    mysql_error();
};

?>
```

Comment: You need to post the contents of `conect.php`

Comment: You probably misspelled connect.php as conect.php

Comment: Also switch to use mysqli methods, mysql functions are deprecated

Comment: You'll want to echo `mysql_error()`

Comment: you are using `'` instead of `\``

Comment: Or PDO. (15 characters)

Comment: Please don't use deprecated SQL extentsions, use mysqli instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect. You only quote STRINGS in a query, not field names or values. Quoting them reduces them to strings, and they'll no longer be field/table names. Try

```
SELECT food, calories
FROM food
ORDER BY id
```

instead. Note the utter lack of quotes in there.

Comment: Thank you so much omg lol it worked i think the ting was is that i was going off a older video and he was using it the way i typed it but now it works correctly thanks again.

Comment: general tip: probably 90% of php tips/techniques on the net are obsolete, bad, or just plain wrong. your first stop for help should be the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual), followed by the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/), then this place as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli` instead.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("server","db_user","db_pass","db_name") or die(mysqli_error());
$query = "SELECT food, calories
          FROM food 
          ORDER BY id";
if($data_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
    echo "True";
}
else{
    mysqli_error();
}
```

Hope this will help you.